# php, handle multiple dynamic forms on same page

Tags: php, html, forms

I know variations of this question have been asked, but this is a different question than what I have been able to find.  I am building a dynamic list of subscriptions on a single page with information from the database and each subscription has a "cancel" button that uses some form data to make that cancellation happen.

Here is an example of the cancel button on each table row:

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <?php $token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5( session_id() . time(). rand() ); ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sg_subscriptionID" value="<?php echo $subscriptionID; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sg_postID" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Cancel" />
</form>
```

To process the form, at the top of the file I am using `<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']) {} ?>`

This is not working when there are multiple forms on the page, I suspect because it can't differentiate between form data based on the input name "submit".

There isn't a definitive number of forms to be created, so I can't simply just have "submit1", "submit2".  I can add a number dynamically using $count, but how would I check for an array of dynamic numbers in my form handling script?

I appreciate any suggestions for a possible better approach. I am trying to steer clear of ajax if at all possible.

Comment: You don't need this line `<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />`  since you already have `$_SESSION['token']` you can pick up the value any where else on your site except your **posting** the form to a different server.

Comment: Also as much as the accepted answer is correct i would suggest using radio buttons or check buttons to tick on a selected subscriptions then one cancel and accept button a good example of this is yahoo mail box system you select all the mails you wish to delete then hit the delete button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for multiple forms in PHP.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    if (isset($_POST['submit'.$i])){ // check for every forms
        // insert your own logic
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter how many forms you have, it can be identified using this code above.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Just to point out for anyone else using this, you will need to define $count.  I defined it as `$count = 100;`

Answer (score 1):

You can use html input arrays for multiple forms.

Example:-
In you code:-

```
<form method="post" action="">
  <?php $token = $_SESSION['token'] = md5( session_id() . time(). rand() ); ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="token[<?php echo 'form_'.$i ?>]" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sg_subscriptionID[<?php echo 'form_'.$i ?>]" value="<?php echo $subscriptionID; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sg_postID[<?php echo 'form_'.$i ?>]" value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit[<?php echo 'form_'.$i ?>]" value="Cancel" />
</form>
<!-- $i is the key for loop -->
```

And in your php code:-

```
$submits = $_POST['submit'];
// $submits loks like ['form_1']
// Now take the first key
$key = array_keys($submits)[0];
// This is the token for the given submit button
$token = $_POST['token'][$key];
```